# C# Giving control Arrays properties

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, error-handling, controls

I need a few control Arrays for my project but my code is generating errors.

Here is how I give a normal control properties (this code works fine)

```
TextBox stamText = new TextBox()  
{ 
    Location = new Point(15, 50), 
    Text = "55", 
    Width = 30, 
    Height = 30
};
```

Here is the code I tried to do the same but for an array of controls

```
TextBox[] stamText = new TextBox[8]  
{ 
    Location = new Point(15, 50), 
    Text = "55", 
    Width = 30, 
    Height = 30 
};
```

I get errors after each property in the {} saying ";" is expected.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem (giving control arrays properties)?

*****EXTENDED

Okay so my program is a form which keeps track of players stats while we tabletop roleplay.

So say I am in a room with Bill, Jim, and I

I click the "Add player" button on the form and it adds a player along with a bunch of controls to do with that player

```
*AddPlayer Button clicked*
Addplayer()

Public void AddPlayer()
{
*Add a bunch of controls*
 checkbox(i)
 textbox(i)
}
i += 1
```

Now everyone got hit a 10. So i go to alter everyones stamina by -10

```
if for i = 0 to players added 
   if checkbox(i) = checked then textbox(i).text = (text - 10)
```

So i need them to be arrays so i can alter multiple peoples stats at once by going through a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a confusion about the object and collection intializers. The object intializer, which you are using in your first case, works likes this:

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time without having to explicitly invoke a constructor.

```
class Cat
{
    // Auto-implemented properties. 
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

The collection initializer, which you use in your second case, works like this:

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements IEnumerable. The element initializers can be a simple value, an expression or an object initializer. By using a collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple calls to the Add method of the class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.

```
List<int> digits = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

In your example that is throwing the error, you are creating an array of 8 textboxes with the collection intializer but you are passing in the object intializer instead.  The reason you get the error about the `;` is because the `;` is used to separate the objects you are adding into the collection. The compiler expects to see 8 textboxes being added in the collection, each separated by a `;`. Here is one way you could fix this:

```
TextBox[] stamText = new TextBox[8]  
{ 
    new TextBox() { Location = new Point(15, 50), Text = "55", Width = 30, Height = 30 },
    new TextBox() { Location = new Point(15, 50), Text = "55", Width = 30, Height = 30 },
    new TextBox() { Location = new Point(15, 50), Text = "55", Width = 30, Height = 30 },
    new TextBox() { Location = new Point(15, 50), Text = "55", Width = 30, Height = 30 },
    new TextBox() { Location = new Point(15, 50), Text = "55", Width = 30, Height = 30 },
    new TextBox() { Location = new Point(15, 50), Text = "55", Width = 30, Height = 30 },
    new TextBox() { Location = new Point(15, 50), Text = "55", Width = 30, Height = 30 },
    new TextBox() { Location = new Point(15, 50), Text = "55", Width = 30, Height = 30 } 
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realize that there were different uses for {} after initializing.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian says, you need to specify each element when initializing to a non-default value. What you're doing is, you're trying to initialize the "Location, Text, Width, and Height" properties of the `TextBox` array, but the array does not have those properties, `TextBox` does. If you want to "initialize*" an array with a non-default value, best way would be to use a for-loop as in:

```
const int numOfElements = 8;
TextBox[] textBoxArray = new TextBox[numOfElements];

for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++)
{
    textBoxArray[i] = new TextBox()  { Location = new Point(15, 50), Text = "55", Width = 30, Height = 30 };
}
```

**: This is not really initializing, as your array was already initialized with default value when you declared it. It's more of "populating" I guess.*

Comment: Hmm. This whole process of creating control arrays is to do with efficiency though.

Instead of creating 100 textbox's for 100 players my program adds a new textbox every time a new player is added (triggered by a button)

I'm going to see if a counter works so I could do:

stamLab(counter) {details}

Comment: Ian's solution creates a new element for each one too. If you want all elements of the array to point to the same TextBox instance, then you should declare that instance once and just make each element of the array point to that instance (though I don't know why you need this, maybe we could help more if you explain why you're using this.)

Comment: Where do you exactly add those controls? They should be added in different places (preferable in different control groups), your code adds them on top of each other at the moment.

Comment: Yeah I've realize that while writting it. Really i need a TextBox[] textBoxArray = new TextBox[numOfElements]; in my initialization code. And then I need to write this every time addplayer is called: Textbox[i] {details}

Comment: Thank you for you time hattenn. You've really shown me where my problem is at :)

Comment: No problem. You will have to write a bit more sophisticated system for that, but it should be a fun exercise. Maybe you can try creating a form and adding a DataGridView to it that keeps a player's stats. Then you can add new players (maybe create a "Player" class) and then in that class have a list that can contain all the stats. Then you can bind that list to your `DataGridView`, so it will show the player's stats. This way, you can keep a list of players and have a combo box on your Form that contains the names of the players, and every time the player is changed you can change the...

Comment: ... DataSource property of the DataGridView to the relevant player's stats container.

Comment: Wow I've only just realized I've not actually been creating players just ther attributes. I'll rearrange all the code into a more suitable class. Thanks again and I'll try your idea.